# How to detect if VS Code is installed on a given Windows machine

Tags: wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-code

I'm building a WIX Toolset based installer for a product that includes a VS Code extension as one of its components. How can I reliably detect if VS Code is installed on a given Windows machine to do a proper prerequisite check?

Is there some registry key/value that has a high chance of staying fairly stable over the future VS Code releases? 
For example: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\Code.exe\shell\open\command

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code can be [launched from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_launching-from-command-line). Thus you could use a command like `code --version` to check whether it is installed or not.

Comment: Unfortunately the WIX based installer requires a fully qualified path to the code.cmd file to be able to execute it.